# Consuming RabbitMQ messages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I was using https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq in a Laravel application to put messages on a RabbitMQ queue and to consume them in another Laravel application via `php artisan rabbitmq:consume` or `php artisan queue:work` (and that setup worked).

But I had to switch to using https://github.com/ssi-anik/laravel-amqp and I'm not clear on how to consume messages - what is the equivalent of the `rabbitmq:consume` or `queue:work` from the previous plugin? There's directions in the readme that provide PHP code to consume, but no command that can be run and left running to constantly watch a queue and consume messages. Are users expected to create a custom command that would do it?

ChatGPT insists that `amqp:consume` is the one to run but that returns:

`ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "amqp" namespace.`

By the way I am able to successfully get messages onto the queue using this line: `Amqp::connection('queuename')->publish(json_encode($mydata));`

I'm on Laravel 9.52.10, anik/amqp 2.3 and anik/laravel-amqp 1.4.

Comment: Just from looking at the source of laravel-amqp, it doesn't appear to have any commands to run.

Comment: Thanks @Bennett, I did suspect there actually aren't any commands. So I guess the only possibility that leaves is that users are expected to create a custom command? Unless there's another way to have a watcher/consumer running constantly in the background?